# How i do a push properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm making a login page in react. When the login is done my react needs to redirect to my page `FrontFeed`. I'am using `this.props.history.push('/feed');` to push the page, but when acess the login page the and put my credentials the login redirect to the login with diferent url and i need to make login again, and only the second time the login redirect to the `FrontFeed`.

When i access the page for the first time

[image]

I made a login (The credentials are right) and the page me redirect to the same page but a diferent url `/#/` -> `/?#/`. The funtions are not called because the requisitions aren't made, and the local storage don't save nothing.

But the second time i made login, everything works fine, the requisitions are maden and the local storage is stored, and my page is redirect to `http://localhost:3000/?#/feed`.

I'm not sure if i'm using the `react-router-dom` right. But there's something wrong.

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import './css/App.css';

import MainPage from './pages/MainPage.js';

function App() {

  return (
    <MainPage/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/MainPage.css';
import FrontFeed from './FrontFeed.js';
import Login from './Login.js';

import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class MainPage extends Component{

  componentDidMount() {
    var token = localStorage.getItem('Token');
    console.log(token);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
        <div className="app">
            <div className="content">
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
              <Route path="/feed" component={FrontFeed}/>
            </div>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/Login.css';
import UserService from '../services/UserService'
import {ToastsContainer, ToastsContainerPosition, ToastsStore} from 'react-toasts';

export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      user: new UserService(),
      password: '',
      username: '',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var token = localStorage.getItem('Token');
    if(token) {
      this.props.history.push('/feed');
    }
  }

  handleChangeUsername(event) {
    this.setState({username: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangePassword(event) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.state.user.login(this.state.username, this.state.password).then(res => {
      if (res.data.super) {
        localStorage.setItem('Token', res.data.key);
        ToastsStore.success('Login Sucess!');
      } else {
        ToastsStore.success("You aren't super!");
      }
      this.props.history.push('/feed');
    }).catch(err => {
      ToastsStore.success('Login Failed');
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="loginContent">
        <ToastsContainer position={ToastsContainerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER}
                         store={ToastsStore}/>
        <div className="title">Login to ADM</div>
        <div className="credentialsContainer">
          <form onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}>
            <div className="username">
              Username:
              <div className="inputUsername">
                <input type="text"
                       value={this.state.username}
                       onChange={e => this.handleChangeUsername(e)} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="password">
              Password:
              <div className="inputPassword">
                <input type="password"
                       value={this.state.password}
                       onChange={e => this.handleChangePassword(e)} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="submitButton">
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put `event.preventDefault();` inside of the handleSubmit function, it prevents the page to reload so this is why your functions are not getting executed on the first time

a typical form will send data to the action with a method

`<form action="/action_page.php" method="post">`

but since you are using the `handleSubmit()` and not an action then it will send data to no where (you can read more about forms here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp )

when you submit the first time, you will see in the url the input values that you have in the form (if you put names on them) but since you didn't put names on them in your form thus you don't see them in the url (assuming from the code that you provided above)

`event.preventDefault()` prevents the usual form submit and the page reload so you can execute the functions inside of it (same thing I have did to a project I worked on)

after you put `event.preventDefault();` to the form, the login will work from the first attempt and react router will redirect it to the `/feed` page

hope my answer helped a bit

Comment: I understanding my mistake, i saw the form's page in react site, and there's this `event.preventDefault();`, but i think i erase in some moment of the code. now i understanding the use of that. Thanks.